# R cran: saving a markdown document with command line

Tags: r, r-markdown, pander

I am trying to create a package that generates automatically R markdown document and save then for the user.

For creating the document, I will use the pander package ([Programmatically generating formatted text in R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539251/programmatically-generating-formatted-text-in-r-markdown)) but impossible to find the way to save the generated document with a line of R command...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Cha

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what you are looking after but I think the refclass way might be useful on your end: https://rapporter.github.io/pander/#live-report-generation

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing what you call "generated document" is a string of characters that you want to be the content of a Rmarkdown file.

You can use

```
cat("This is \n a string",file="myFile.Rmd",append=FALSE,sep="\n")
```

This line creates a file named `myFile.Rmd` which content is

```
This is 
 a string
```

You just have to change the first argument to whatever you want to be the content of your file.

Comment: Thank you too Freguglia,

However, how to deal with a full document not only using strings but also calculations ... (see my comment above)

Again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
# My data to be tabulated
mydata <- mtcars[1:4, 1:6]

# Create a table
mytable <- pander_return(mydata, style="rmarkdown")

# Open a file connection
myfile <- file("Tst.txt")

# Write my table to my file
writeLines(mytable, myfile)
```

In `Tst.txt`:

```
|       &nbsp;       | mpg  | cyl | disp | hp  | drat |  wt   |
|:------------------:|:----:|:---:|:----:|:---:|:----:|:-----:|
|   **Mazda RX4**    |  21  |  6  | 160  | 110 | 3.9  | 2.62  |
| **Mazda RX4 Wag**  |  21  |  6  | 160  | 110 | 3.9  | 2.875 |
|   **Datsun 710**   | 22.8 |  4  | 108  | 93  | 3.85 | 2.32  |
| **Hornet 4 Drive** | 21.4 |  6  | 258  | 110 | 3.08 | 3.215 |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea, the problem is that the file will not be only a table but rather a whole document with calculations. I take the example of RSudio:

---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Charlotte"
date: "7 février 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown


```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

I tried to embed this script in  pander_return as you suggest but R does not like that :D.

Do you see the problem ?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the package `blogdown` (https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown)? Maybe it will help you achieve what you would like to do!

I think with this type of package, you will be able to save all the file and its content. That's what i would use in that case!

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I will have a  look to see if it can fit...Would be soooo coool ;)

Comment: Keep me in the loop. I'll be glad to know if it's working for you or not ;-)

Comment: Ok, I think I found the way but I am not sure so I will test it first and let you know :)

Comment: OKay, nice, keep in touch. Have a nice day!